# Locally Testing FB log in for post to wall does not allow Localhost in AppDomains

Tags: .net, facebook, localhost

I am trying to locally test a fb app that posts a photo to the user's timeline.  I tried adding localhost:xxxx in the AppDomains box on the test app set up, but I get a message that reads, "Top-level domains are not allowed".  I need to be able to debug the .Net code, but this prevents the testing.
Any ideas would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Domain should only be "localhost", no Protocol or Port. Just add a platform (for example, "Website") with `http://localhost:xxxx`.